# trying to use while read loop to save result to an array

Tags: arrays, linux, while-loop

Quick question, can i do this?:

```
while IFS=: read menu script
do
    echo "$x. $menu"
    command[x]="$script"
    let x++
done < file.txt
```

read two strings per line from a file, print one and save the other to an array..

file.txt looks like this:

```
File Operations:~/scripts/project/File_Operations.sh
Directory Operations:~/scripts/project/Directory_Operations.sh
Process Management:~/scripts/project/Process_Management.sh
Search Operations:~/scripts/project/Search_Operations.sh
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Looks right. 2 things.

- You need to initialise x. `x=0`
- When you use x as a subscript it needs the `$`. i.e. `command[$x]="$script"`
- And done forget the `{}`s when referencing the command array. e.g. `${command[0]}`

Comment: I had initialised x=1, when i changed to x=0 it worked
thank you for a quick response :)

Comment: `command[x]=$script` works ok for me. Inside of `[]`, you can use any arithmetic expression.

Answer (score 0):

What shell are you using? Works for me in `bash`, I just prepended the following two lines to the script:

```
#!/bin/bash
x=0
```

Without setting `$x` to 0, the user is presented with

```
. File Operations
1. Directory Operations
2. Process Management
3. Search Operations
```

Comment: thank you for quick answer!
My problem wasn't the echo, but it never wrote anything to the array but that was probably because i had initialised x=1, so it never got to the first index of the array
when i changed to x=0 it worked perfectly :)